# How to get number of rows in excel which contains data(excluding blank or empty cells) in one particular column using JAVA, APACHE POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Trying to read excel where i need to extract number of rows in one column which contains data or value except blank or empty cells. And store cell values inside string array I tried using sheet.getLastRowNum() but didn't worked for me. Can anyone suggest the way out.

following is what I tried so far

```
private void readExcel() 
{
    InputStream ExcelFileToRead = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/Public/template.xlsx");
    XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(ExcelFileToRead);
    XSSFWorkbook test = new XSSFWorkbook();
    XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
    XSSFRow row=null;
    XSSFCell cell;   
    String[] strArray=null;
    int i=10;

    for(i=10;i<this.sheet.getLastRowNum();i++)
    {
        if( (getCell("G"+i)!=null) ) 
        {                
            strArray[index]= strArray[index] + getCell("G"+i).toString() ;
        }           
    }
      System.out.println(strArray);
}

private XSSFCell getCell(String cellName)
{
    Pattern r = Pattern.compile("^([A-Z]+)([0-9]+)$");
    Matcher m = r.matcher(cellName);
    if(m.matches()) 
    {
        String columnName = m.group(1);
        int rowNumber = Integer.parseInt(m.group(2));
        if(rowNumber > 0) 
        {
            return wb.getSheetAt(0).getRow(rowNumber-1).getCell(CellReference.convertColStringToIndex(columnName));
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Why didn't it work for you? Have you tried `sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows()`? If you dont want to read empty cells, why not filter them out?

Comment: sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows() was considering blank cells as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you know how many columns you have, since the question is only about the number of non-empty cells in a column.

Here is a method which would deliver the correct result:

```
 public static int getNumberOfNonEmptyCells(XSSFSheet sheet,int columnIndex) {
        int numberOfNonEmptyCells = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= sheet.getLastRowNum();i++) {
            XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(i);
            if (row != null) {
                XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(columnIndex);
                if (cell != null && cell.getCellType() != Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) {
                    numberOfNonEmptyCells++;
                }
            }
        }
        return numberOfNonEmptyCells;
    }
```

Comment: Easy to break this solution. I just created a file which contains 4 values. Yet your code outputs 5.

Answer (score 3):

A better version than the accepted answer:

```
public static int getNumberOfNonEmptyCells(XSSFSheet sheet, int columnIndex) {
    int numberOfNonEmptyCells = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
        XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(i);
        if (row != null) {
            XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(columnIndex);
            if (cell != null && cell.getCellType() != CellType.BLANK && !cell.getRawValue().trim().isEmpty()) {
                numberOfNonEmptyCells++;
            }
        }
    }
    return numberOfNonEmptyCells;
}
```

This method has 2 advantages:

1. It doesn't use deprecated methods as of apache-poi 4.0.0
2. It doesn't count empty cells which the currently accepted answer does.

---

As I can't upload the workbook, here is the xml part of the worksheet that breaks the accepted method:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<worksheet xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:x14ac="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/ac" mc:Ignorable="x14ac">
   <dimension ref="A1:A5" />
   <sheetViews>
      <sheetView tabSelected="1" workbookViewId="0">
         <selection activeCell="A3" sqref="A3" />
      </sheetView>
   </sheetViews>
   <sheetFormatPr defaultRowHeight="15" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25" />
   <sheetData>
      <row r="1" spans="1:1" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25">
         <c r="A1">
            <v>1</v>
         </c>
      </row>
      <row r="2" spans="1:1" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25">
         <c r="A2">
            <v>2</v>
         </c>
      </row>
      <row r="3" spans="1:1" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25">
         <c r="A3">
            <v></v>
         </c>
      </row>

      <row r="4" spans="1:1" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25">
         <c r="A4">
            <v>4</v>
         </c>
      </row>
      <row r="5" spans="1:1" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25">
         <c r="A5">
            <v>5</v>
         </c>
      </row>
   </sheetData>
   <pageMargins left="0.7" right="0.7" top="0.75" bottom="0.75" header="0.3" footer="0.3" />
</worksheet>
```

To use this, do the following:

1. Create an empty excel file and save it.
2. Rename it to .zip file (excel is basically a zip archive)
3. Open the archive and navigate to `\xl\worksheets`
4. Replace any `sheetX.xml` file with the XML above
5. Rename the file back to .xlsx
6. Run the accepted version and see output 5
7. Run my version and see output 4
8. Open excel file to see that only 4 values are present

Comment: This is really helpful. Thank you.